# How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

How can I create a `UIColor` from a **hexadecimal** string format, such as `#00FF00`?

Comment: Erica also has a [great color extension category for iOS and OSX](https://github.com/erica/uicolor-utilities).

Comment: Here is another library: https://github.com/burhanuddin353/TFTColor

Answer (score 742):

I've found the simplest way to do this is with a macro.  Just include it in your header and it's available throughout your project.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

[uicolor macro with hex values](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/07/uicolor-macro-with-hex-values.html)

Also formatted version of this code:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
                 blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >>  0))/255.0 \
                alpha:1.0]
```

Usage:

```
label.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xBC1128);
```

#### Swift:

```swift
static func UIColorFromRGB(_ rgbValue: Int) -> UIColor! {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((Float((rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 255.0),
        green: CGFloat((Float((rgbValue & 0x00ff00) >> 8)) / 255.0),
        blue: CGFloat((Float((rgbValue & 0x0000ff) >> 0)) / 255.0),
        alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: This is great except it doesn't do what the questioner asks, which is to convert a hex STRING into a UIColor. This converts an integer to a UIColor.

Comment: @MohamedA.Karim That is an example of returning a UIColor from a hex format integer (0x...) not a hex format string ("#..."). Great if that's what you want, but not what the questioner asked for.

Comment: @darrinm It's really not hard to change a HEX format string into a HEX format integer (You can do it with one short line of code using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"0x").

Comment: @ScottKohlert Your line of code converts one hex format string (prefixed with "#") into another hex format string (prefixed with "0x"). It does not produce an integer.

Comment: @darrinm the OP was looking for a string format starting with a #, I just added the line of code so it would convert the # into the format required by the #define statement (Ox...). See the OP's question: How can I create a UIColor from a hexadecimal STRING format, such as #00FF00

Comment: @ScottKohlert Perhaps some day the OP will return to bless one of these answers and we'll know for sure :). I assume Rupesh is dealing with the string at runtime, in which case what matters is converting the "#00FF00" string into parameters accepted by one of UIColor's constructors. Several answers here show ways to do this, but not the one we're commenting on.

Comment: How to use this like [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor?

Comment: To convert a hex format string to an integer for use with this macro, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer.

Comment: Is there any advantage using a macro instead of a function?

Comment: @ratsimihah There is an advantage to using as a macro but you won't find it in this particular solution, however had the macro used the `##` operator then your input could be just `FF0000` instead of `0xFF0000` which would be nice for lots of coders copy pasting hex colors from, say, photoshop. To accomplish this, just replace occurrences of `rgbValue` with `0x ## rgbValue` in the body of macro.

Comment: If you have the hex in `NSString` format as the OP explicitly requests and want to use this nice function posted here, you can convert it like this: `unsigned long int hexValue = strtoul(hexString.UTF8String, NULL, 16);`. Full details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163698/427959

Answer (score 390):

A concise solution:

```
// Assumes input like "#00FF00" (#RRGGBB).
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: And a good method for doing the reverse conversion (like if you're storing colors in core data / a remote database) can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884227/how-do-i-convert-a-uicolor-to-a-hexadecimal-string

Comment: A perfect solution. If your hex string comes from a (very poorly documented) API, be sure to test against shorthand hex codes like #FFF or #FC0. You'll need to change them to #FFFFFF/#FFCCOO.

Comment: You might also want to add `if ( [hexString rangeOfString:@"#"].location == 0 )` before the `setScanLocation` line to make the `#` optional.

Comment: can you please add the reverse method.

Comment: For the lazy: **SWIFT** version [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd07ecf47591c9f9ed1a).

Comment: Heh `[scanner setScanLocation:[hexString rangeOfString:@"#"].location+1];`

Comment: @Darrinm  if i pass the value "364050" string to colorFromHexString its gives different color, do I need to include #364050 ?

Answer (score 204):

I've got a solution that is 100% compatible with the hex format strings used by Android, which I found very helpful when doing cross-platform mobile development.  It lets me use one color palate for both platforms.  Feel free to reuse without attribution, or under the Apache license if you prefer.

```
#import "UIColor+HexString.h"

@interface UIColor(HexString)

+ (UIColor *) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) hexString;
+ (CGFloat) colorComponentFrom: (NSString *) string start: (NSUInteger) start length: (NSUInteger) length;

@end


@implementation UIColor(HexString)

+ (UIColor *) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) hexString {
    NSString *colorString = [[hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"#" withString: @""] uppercaseString];
    CGFloat alpha, red, blue, green;
    switch ([colorString length]) {
        case 3: // #RGB
            alpha = 1.0f;
            red   = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 1];
            green = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 1 length: 1];
            blue  = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 1];
            break;
        case 4: // #ARGB
            alpha = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 1];
            red   = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 1 length: 1];
            green = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 1];
            blue  = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 3 length: 1];          
            break;
        case 6: // #RRGGBB
            alpha = 1.0f;
            red   = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 2];
            green = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 2];
            blue  = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 4 length: 2];                      
            break;
        case 8: // #AARRGGBB
            alpha = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 0 length: 2];
            red   = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 2 length: 2];
            green = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 4 length: 2];
            blue  = [self colorComponentFrom: colorString start: 6 length: 2];                      
            break;
        default:
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid color value" format: @"Color value %@ is invalid.  It should be a hex value of the form #RBG, #ARGB, #RRGGBB, or #AARRGGBB", hexString];
            break;
    }
    return [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: alpha];
}

+ (CGFloat) colorComponentFrom: (NSString *) string start: (NSUInteger) start length: (NSUInteger) length {
    NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(start, length)];
    NSString *fullHex = length == 2 ? substring : [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", substring, substring];
    unsigned hexComponent;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString: fullHex] scanHexInt: &hexComponent];
    return hexComponent / 255.0;
}

@end
```

#### Swift:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(hexString: String?) {
        let input: String! = (hexString ?? "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")
            .uppercased()
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        switch (input.count) {
        case 3 /* #RGB */:
            red = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 0, length: 1)
            green = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 1, length: 1)
            blue = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 2, length: 1)
            break
        case 4 /* #ARGB */:
            alpha = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 0, length: 1)
            red = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 1, length: 1)
            green = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 2, length: 1)
            blue = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 3, length: 1)
            break
        case 6 /* #RRGGBB */:
            red = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 0, length: 2)
            green = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 2, length: 2)
            blue = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 4, length: 2)
            break
        case 8 /* #AARRGGBB */:
            alpha = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 0, length: 2)
            red = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 2, length: 2)
            green = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 4, length: 2)
            blue = Self.colorComponent(from: input, start: 6, length: 2)
            break
        default:
            NSException.raise(NSExceptionName("Invalid color value"), format: "Color value \"%@\" is invalid.  It should be a hex value of the form #RBG, #ARGB, #RRGGBB, or #AARRGGBB", arguments:getVaList([hexString ?? ""]))
        }
        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    
    static func colorComponent(from string: String!, start: Int, length: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let substring = (string as NSString)
            .substring(with: NSRange(location: start, length: length))
        let fullHex = length == 2 ? substring : "\(substring)\(substring)"
        var hexComponent: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: fullHex)
            .scanHexInt64(&hexComponent)
        return CGFloat(Double(hexComponent) / 255.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: in `colorComponentFrom:start:length:`, shouldn't you have `return hexComponent / 0xFF; // divide by 255, not 256` ?  The largest hex value you should get back is 0xFF, thus that is what you should be dividing by 0xFF (255).

Comment: Good catch Sam.  Edited to reflect the change.

Comment: This is great, cheers. Also, instead of a category on UIColor you could make one on NSString to be able to have syntax like `[@"#538aa4" toColor]`

Comment: This solution is great,
I would suggest to add "Private" for the name of the private interface to avoid a compiler warning.

    @interface UIColor(Private)

Comment: Why isn't colorWithHexString declared in the interface?

Comment: Nice solution. However imo it should also be able to handle hexString=nil and give black

Comment: Nice. You should put the *other* function in the interface, though.

Comment: @MicahHainline How to catch exception in swift? thoughts

Answer (score 72):

There's a nice post on how to tackle the OP's question of extracting a `UIColor` from a hex string. The solution presented below is different from others because it supports string values that may include '0x' or '#' prefixed to the hex string representation... (see usage)

Here's the main bit...

```
- (UIColor *)getUIColorObjectFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
  // Convert hex string to an integer
  unsigned int hexint = [self intFromHexString:hexStr];
 
  // Create a color object, specifying alpha as well
  UIColor *color =
    [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255
    green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255
    blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255
    alpha:alpha];
 
  return color;
}
```

Helper method...

```
- (unsigned int)intFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr
{
  unsigned int hexInt = 0;
 
  // Create scanner
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
 
  // Tell scanner to skip the # character
  [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];
 
  // Scan hex value
  [scanner scanHexInt:&hexInt];
 
  return hexInt;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *hexStr1 = @"123ABC";
NSString *hexStr2 = @"#123ABC";
NSString *hexStr3 = @"0x123ABC";

UIColor *color1 = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:hexStr1 alpha:.9];
NSLog(@"UIColor: %@", color1);
 
UIColor *color2 = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:hexStr2 alpha:.9];
NSLog(@"UIColor: %@", color2);
 
UIColor *color3 = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:hexStr3 alpha:.9];
NSLog(@"UIColor: %@", color3);
```

[Complete Reference Article](http://iosdevelopertips.com/conversion/create-uicolor-object-from-a-hex-string-nsstring.html)

### Swift 2+

I've ported this solution to Swift 2.2. Note that I've changed the `alpha` parameter to use a default set to 1.0. I've also updated the int type to `UInt32` as required by the `NSScanner` class in Swift 2.2.

```
func colorWithHexString(hexString: String, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor {
    
    // Convert hex string to an integer
    let hexint = Int(self.intFromHexString(hexString))
    let red = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
    let green = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
    let blue = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0 
    
    // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
    let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    return color
}

func intFromHexString(hexStr: String) -> UInt32 {
    var hexInt: UInt32 = 0
    // Create scanner
    let scanner: NSScanner = NSScanner(string: hexStr)
    // Tell scanner to skip the # character
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "#")
    // Scan hex value
    scanner.scanHexInt(&hexInt)
    return hexInt
}
```

### Swift 4+

Using the same logic with changes applied for swift 4,

```
func colorWithHexString(hexString: String, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor {
    
    // Convert hex string to an integer
    let hexint = Int(self.intFromHexString(hexStr: hexString))
    let red = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
    let green = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
    let blue = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0
    
    // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
    let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    return color
}

func intFromHexString(hexStr: String) -> UInt32 {
    var hexInt: UInt32 = 0
    // Create scanner
    let scanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: hexStr)
    // Tell scanner to skip the # character
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "#")
    // Scan hex value
    scanner.scanHexInt32(&hexInt)
    return hexInt
}
```

### Swift 5 (iOS 13)+

The following shows an update that works given the SDK deprecation of `scanHexInt32`. I've wrapped the code into a Swift playground file.

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface
  
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = colorWithHexString(hexString: "22F728")
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
    
    func colorWithHexString(hexString: String, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor {

        // Convert hex string to an integer
        let hexint = Int(self.intFromHexString(hexStr: hexString))
        let red = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((hexint & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0

        // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
        let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
        return color
    }

    func intFromHexString(hexStr: String) -> UInt32 {
        var hexInt: UInt32 = 0
        // Create scanner
        let scanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: hexStr)
        // Tell scanner to skip the # character
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "#")
        // Scan hex value
        hexInt = UInt32(bitPattern: scanner.scanInt32(representation: .hexadecimal) ?? 0)
        return hexInt
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

> Color Hex References
>
> [HTML Color Names and Codes](http://www.htmlcolorname.com)
>
> [Color Hex Color Codes](https://www.colorcodehex.com)

Comment: The Swift snippets posted here seem to misunderstand the purpose of optionals in Swift, which is to contain values which may never exist. The question to ask in whether a parameter needs to be an optional is whether someone may need the ability to set it to nil. Does it possibly make sense for `alpha` to *ever* be set to nil? Because this method gives people that ability, and if someone should decide to set `alpha` to nil, the forced unwrapping of that optional will invariably lead to a crash. I haven't edited it out, though, in case there's some justification of which I'm not aware.

Comment: @JonathanThornton - Thanks for the heads up. Resolved.

Comment: Working on a legacy project and the Objective-C solution works very well... except... oddly... @"​#ffc107" and @"​#e040fb" refuse to cooperate! Thoughts?

Comment: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in macOS 10.15

Comment: @Sentry.co - Updated code to deal with deprecated method.

Comment: @Nathaniel - Tried both of those color values with the latest code and they seem to work as planned.

Answer (score 54):

**This is a function that takes a hex string and returns a UIColor.**
*(You can enter hex strings with either format: `#ffffff` or `ffffff`)*

**Usage:**

```
var color1 = hexStringToUIColor("#d3d3d3")
```

**Swift 4:**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
      cString = cString.substringFromIndex(cString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
      return UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

---

Source: [arshad/gist:de147c42d7b3063ef7bc](https://gist.github.com/arshad/de147c42d7b3063ef7bc)

Comment: I've seen in SVG, where there is a small version of the hex string with 3 characters, like #F0F.

Comment: That is shorthand notation, where '#F0F' is equivalent to '#FF00FF'.  It would be simple to write a function that checked for shorthand and expanded it.

Answer (score 41):

Use this Category :

in the file **UIColor+Hexadecimal.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor(Hexadecimal)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString;

@end
```

in the file **UIColor+Hexadecimal.m**

```
#import "UIColor+Hexadecimal.h"

@implementation UIColor(Hexadecimal)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

---

In Class you want use it :

```
#import "UIColor+Hexadecimal.h"
```

and:

```
[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#6e4b4b"];
```

Comment: No alpha handling

Answer (score 34):

You can make a extension like this

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: UInt, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(hex & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
}
```

And use it anywhere like this

```
let color1 = UIColor(hex: 0xffffff)
let color2 = UIColor(hex: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.2)
```

Comment: Dead simple, definitely my favorite.

Comment: Thanks, this one is great, so concise compared to other walls of text!

Comment: nice function but it does not in any way answer the question.

Comment: @mah This is exactly the question i think, how to create a UIColor from hexstring

Comment: @ManuGupta you might notice a complete lack of any string handling in this answer. A hex number is not a hex string. The question explicitly states a string and though it doesn't have quotes in it, `#00FF00` is clearly intended to be a character string. As others have said it's simple, concise. But if it doesn't deal with strings it can't possibly answer a question asking how to deal with strings.

Answer (score 28):

A great Swift implementation (updated for Xcode 7) using extensions, pulled together from a variety of different answers and places. You will also need the string extensions at the end.

Use:

```
let hexColor = UIColor(hex: "#00FF00")
```

NOTE: I added an option for 2 additional digits to the end of the standard 6 digit hex value for an alpha channel (pass in value of `00`-`99`). If this offends you, just remove it. You could implement it to pass in an optional alpha parameter.

Extension:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(var hex: String) {
        var alpha: Float = 100
        let hexLength = hex.characters.count
        if !(hexLength == 7 || hexLength == 9) {
            // A hex must be either 7 or 9 characters (#RRGGBBAA)
            print("improper call to 'colorFromHex', hex length must be 7 or 9 chars (#GGRRBBAA)")
            self.init(white: 0, alpha: 1)
            return
        }

        if hexLength == 9 {
            // Note: this uses String subscripts as given below
            alpha = hex[7...8].floatValue
            hex = hex[0...6]
        }

        // Establishing the rgb color
        var rgb: UInt32 = 0
        let s: NSScanner = NSScanner(string: hex)
        // Setting the scan location to ignore the leading `#`
        s.scanLocation = 1
        // Scanning the int into the rgb colors
        s.scanHexInt(&rgb)

        // Creating the UIColor from hex int
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha / 100)
        )
    }
}
```

String extensions:
[Float source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24088249/1429262)
[Subscript source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35040346/1429262)

```
extension String {

    /**
    Returns the float value of a string
    */
    var floatValue: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }

    /**
    Subscript to allow for quick String substrings ["Hello"][0...1] = "He"
    */
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            let start = self.startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
            let end = self.startIndex.advancedBy(r.endIndex - 1)
            return self.substringWithRange(start..<end)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you also using a String extension to get its subscript? eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/3220708

Comment: @CraigGrummitt oh my! Haha, yes. I have a decent compiled list of extensions and subscripts I sometimes (sadly) forget what is and is not included in the standard language feature set. I updated my answer including the source you gave. Not sure if I even got it from there but it sure looks close.

Comment: You might want to mention that it's a String extension. Also you seem to have missed String floatValue extension: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24088249/3220708 Other than that, good work!

Comment: Where is countElements() func?

Comment: `countElements()` was replaced with `count()` in Swift 1.2, it is built into the language. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You know what? There is a bug in your code! In the first commented line and in the next one, you should replace `#GGRRBBAA` by `#RRGGBBAA`, should not you? ;-)

Comment: You are correct. I have fixed the comment. Thanks for pointing it out (feel free to edit things like that).

Answer (score 26):

There is no builtin conversion from a hexadecimal string to a `UIColor` (or `CGColor`) that I'm aware of. However, you can easily write a couple of functions for this purpose - for example, see [iphone development accessing uicolor components](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ar)

Comment: +1 If you scroll way down, the method in question is +colorWithHexString:.

Comment: @RobNapier `+colorWithHexString:` doesn't work. At least in my case. :)

Answer (score 20):

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexaString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        let chars = Array(hexaString.dropFirst())
        self.init(red:   .init(strtoul(String(chars[0...1]),nil,16))/255,
                  green: .init(strtoul(String(chars[2...3]),nil,16))/255,
                  blue:  .init(strtoul(String(chars[4...5]),nil,16))/255,
                  alpha: alpha)}
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let redColor       = UIColor(hexaString: "#FF0000")              // r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 1,0
let transparentRed = UIColor(hexaString: "#FF0000", alpha: 0.5)  // r 1,0 g 0,0 b 0,0 a 0,5
```

---

---

Another option is to convert the hexavalue to an unsigned integer and extract the corresponding values from it:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexaString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(hexa: UInt(hexaString.dropFirst(), radix: 16) ?? 0, alpha: alpha)
    }
    convenience init(hexa: UInt, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red:   .init((hexa & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255,
                  green: .init((hexa & 0xff00  ) >>  8) / 255,
                  blue:  .init( hexa & 0xff    )        / 255,
                  alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

---

```
let purpleColor       = UIColor(hexaString: "#FF00FF")    // r 1,0 g 0,0 b 1,0 a 1,0
let transparentYellow = UIColor(hexaString: "#FFFF00", alpha: 0.5)  // r 1,0 g 1,0 b 0,0 a 0,5
```

Comment: best short solution ever

Answer (score 16):

I found a good `UIColor` category for this, [**UIColor+PXExtensions**](https://gist.github.com/hlung/ab9c71c2e98d5da845aa).

Usage: `UIColor *mycolor = [UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:@"#BADA55"];`

And, just in case the link to my gist fails, here is the actual implementation code:

```
//
//  UIColor+PXExtensions.m
//

#import "UIColor+UIColor_PXExtensions.h"

@implementation UIColor (UIColor_PXExtensions)

+ (UIColor*)pxColorWithHexValue:(NSString*)hexValue
{
    //Default
    UIColor *defaultResult = [UIColor blackColor];

    //Strip prefixed # hash
    if ([hexValue hasPrefix:@"#"] && [hexValue length] > 1) {
        hexValue = [hexValue substringFromIndex:1];
    }

    //Determine if 3 or 6 digits
    NSUInteger componentLength = 0;
    if ([hexValue length] == 3)
    {
        componentLength = 1;
    }
    else if ([hexValue length] == 6)
    {
        componentLength = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return defaultResult;
    }

    BOOL isValid = YES;
    CGFloat components[3];

    //Seperate the R,G,B values
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        NSString *component = [hexValue substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(componentLength * i, componentLength)];
        if (componentLength == 1) {
            component = [component stringByAppendingString:component];
        }
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:component];
        unsigned int value;
        isValid &= [scanner scanHexInt:&value];
        components[i] = (CGFloat)value / 256.0f;
    }

    if (!isValid) {
        return defaultResult;
    }

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:components[0]
                           green:components[1]
                            blue:components[2]
                           alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok, I added the implementation code :)

Answer (score 14):

swift version. Use as a Function or an Extension.

Function

```
  func UIColorFromRGB(colorCode: String, alpha: Float = 1.0) -> UIColor{
    var scanner = NSScanner(string:colorCode)
    var color:UInt32 = 0;
    scanner.scanHexInt(&color)
    
    let mask = 0x000000FF
    let r = CGFloat(Float(Int(color >> 16) & mask)/255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(Float(Int(color >> 8) & mask)/255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(Float(Int(color) & mask)/255.0)
    
    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
}
```

Extension

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(colorCode: String, alpha: Float = 1.0){
        var scanner = NSScanner(string:colorCode)
        var color:UInt32 = 0;
        scanner.scanHexInt(&color)
        
        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = CGFloat(Float(Int(color >> 16) & mask)/255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(Float(Int(color >> 8) & mask)/255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(Float(Int(color) & mask)/255.0)
        
        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

How to call

```
let hexColorFromFunction = UIColorFromRGB("F4C124", alpha: 1.0)
let hexColorFromExtension = UIColor(colorCode: "F4C124", alpha: 1.0)
```

You can also define your `Hex Color` from interface builder.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**SWIFT 4**

You can create a nice `convenience` constructor in the extension like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        var hexInt: UInt32 = 0
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "#")
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&hexInt)

        let red = CGFloat((hexInt & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((hexInt & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((hexInt & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0
        let alpha = alpha

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

And use it later like

```
let color = UIColor(hexString: "#AABBCCDD")
```

Comment: 'scanHexInt32' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Answer (score 11):

This is another alternative.

```
- (UIColor *)colorWithRGBHex:(UInt32)hex
{
    int r = (hex >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g = (hex >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (hex) & 0xFF;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0f
                           green:g / 255.0f
                            blue:b / 255.0f
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: alternative answer to an alternative question... not a reasonable answer to the question on this page though.

Answer (score 11):

You could use various online tools to convert a HEX string to an actual UIColor. Check out [uicolor.org](http://uicolor.org/) or [UI Color Picker](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/ios-uicolor-picker). The output would be converted into Objective-C code, like:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.80 blue:0.80 alpha:1.0];
```

Which you could embed in your application. Hope this helps!

Comment: Another online tool, same name in fact, [UI Color Picker](http://iachieved.it/uicolorpicker.html).

Comment: Generally when people ask for help with code to solve a fairly simple problem like this, an answer that says "first go to some online site..." is really not even close to being the answer the asker wanted.

Answer (score 7):

This is nice with [cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org/) support

https://github.com/mRs-/HexColors

```
// with hash
NSColor *colorWithHex = [NSColor colorWithHexString:@"#ff8942" alpha:1];

// wihtout hash
NSColor *secondColorWithHex = [NSColor colorWithHexString:@"ff8942" alpha:1];

// short handling
NSColor *shortColorWithHex = [NSColor colorWithHexString:@"fff" alpha:1]
```

Comment: Beautiful stuff bro :)

Answer (score 4):

Another version with alpha

```
#define UIColorFromRGBA(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8 ))/255.0 alpha:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift equivalent of @Tom's answer, although receiving RGBA Int value to support transparency:

```
func colorWithHex(aHex: UInt) -> UIColor
{
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat((aHex & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255,
        green: CGFloat((aHex & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255,
        blue: CGFloat((aHex & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255,
        alpha: CGFloat((aHex & 0x000000FF) >> 0) / 255)
}

//usage
var color = colorWithHex(0x7F00FFFF)
```

And if you want to be able to use it from string you could use strtoul:

```
var hexString = "0x7F00FFFF"

let num = strtoul(hexString, nil, 16)

var colorFromString = colorWithHex(num)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `Swift 1.2` version written as an extension to `UIColor`. This allows you to do

```
let redColor = UIColor(hex: "#FF0000")
```

Which I feel is the most natural way of doing it.

```
extension UIColor {
  // Initialiser for strings of format '#_RED_GREEN_BLUE_'
  convenience init(hex: String) {
    let redRange    = Range<String.Index>(start: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(1), end: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(3))
    let greenRange  = Range<String.Index>(start: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(3), end: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(5))
    let blueRange   = Range<String.Index>(start: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(5), end: hex.startIndex.advancedBy(7))

    var red     : UInt32 = 0
    var green   : UInt32 = 0
    var blue    : UInt32 = 0

    NSScanner(string: hex.substringWithRange(redRange)).scanHexInt(&red)
    NSScanner(string: hex.substringWithRange(greenRange)).scanHexInt(&green)
    NSScanner(string: hex.substringWithRange(blueRange)).scanHexInt(&blue)

    self.init(
      red: CGFloat(red) / 255,
      green: CGFloat(green) / 255,
      blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255,
      alpha: 1
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In Xcode 6.3.2 on the line that starts with `let greenRange = ...` I get an exception: `fatal error: can not increment endIndex`

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I've tested this on Xcode 7 beta 3, and it works the same. Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5, iOS 14**

```
convenience init(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    var hexFormatted: String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    
    if hexFormatted.hasPrefix("#") {
        hexFormatted = String(hexFormatted.dropFirst())
    }
    
    assert(hexFormatted.count == 6, "Invalid hex code used.")
    
    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: hexFormatted).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    self.init(red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
              blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
              alpha: alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another implementation allowing strings like `"FFF"` or `"FFFFFF"` and using alpha:

```
+ (UIColor *) colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString alpha: (CGFloat)alpha{
    NSString *cleanString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
    if([cleanString length] == 3) {
        cleanString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@",
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)],
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)],
                       [cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)],[cleanString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)]];
    }
    if([cleanString length] == 6) {
        cleanString = [cleanString stringByAppendingString:@"ff"];
    }

    unsigned int baseValue;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:cleanString] scanHexInt:&baseValue];

    float red = ((baseValue >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0f;
    float green = ((baseValue >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0f;
    float blue = ((baseValue >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0f;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a category for `UIColor` that I can just reuse in my other projects, and added this function:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHex:(unsigned long)hex
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0
                           green:((float)((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0
                            blue:((float)(hex & 0xFF))/255.0
                           alpha:1.0];
}
```

The usage goes like:

```
UIColor *customRedColor = [UIColor colorFromHex:0x990000];
```

This is far faster than passing on a string and converting it to a number then shifting the bits.

You can also import the category from inside your `.pch` file so you can easily use `colorFromHex` everywhere in your app like it's built-in to `UIColor`:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    // Your other stuff here...
    #import "UIColor+HexColor.h"
#endif
```

Comment: At first I liked and tried the #define approach above. Yet like most defines with many () it was hard to extend and debug.  I then fell back to the "Utilities" class method approach.  This works but it introduces a new class name into the namespace.  Then, I saw your posting and I like it a lot because it understands how to use the Objective-C language.  Good show.     I plan on making a similar solution that takes RGB decimal values (eg. red: 24 green: 104 blue: 255)

Answer (score 3):

updated for swift 1.2

```
class func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString: NSString = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString = cString.substringFromIndex(1)
    }

    if (count(cString as String) != 6) {
        return UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    var rString: String = cString.substringToIndex(2)
    var gString: String = (cString.substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
    var bString: String = (cString.substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)

    var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
    NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
    NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
    NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(Float(r) / 255.0), green: CGFloat(Float(g) / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(Float(b) / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1))

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create elegant extension for `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {

convenience init(string: String) {

        var uppercasedString = string.uppercased()
        uppercasedString.remove(at: string.startIndex)

        var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: uppercasedString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Create red color:

```
let red = UIColor(string: "#ff0000")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIColor 
{
    class func fromHexaString(hex:String) -> UIColor
    {
        let scanner           = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation  = 0
        var rgbValue: UInt64  = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}

//you can call like this.

UIColor.fromHexaString(hex:3276b1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = colorWithHex(hex: yourColorCode)
```

- Code for creating **Color** from `hexaDecimalCode`

```
func colorWithHex (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 You Can Get UIColor From String Code Like
   circularSpinner.fillColor = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:@"27b8c8" alpha:9];

 //Function For Hex Color Use
    - (unsigned int)intFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr
    {
        unsigned int hexInt = 0;

        // Create scanner
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];

        // Tell scanner to skip the # character
        [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];

        // Scan hex value
        [scanner scanHexInt:&hexInt];

        return hexInt;
    }




    - (UIColor *)getUIColorObjectFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
    {
        // Convert hex string to an integer
        unsigned int hexint = [self intFromHexString:hexStr];

        // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
        UIColor *color =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255
                        green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255
                         blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255
                        alpha:alpha];

        return color;
    }

    /Function For Hex Color Use
    - (unsigned int)intFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr
    {
        unsigned int hexInt = 0;

        // Create scanner
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];

        // Tell scanner to skip the # character
        [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];

        // Scan hex value
        [scanner scanHexInt:&hexInt];

        return hexInt;
    }




    - (UIColor *)getUIColorObjectFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
    {
        // Convert hex string to an integer
        unsigned int hexint = [self intFromHexString:hexStr];

        // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
        UIColor *color =
        [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255
                        green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255
                         blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255
                        alpha:alpha];

        return color;
    }
```

Comment: if u want use this code,then u call [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:@"27b8c8" alpha:9]; only....

Answer (score 2):

I like to ensure the alpha besides the color, so i write my own category

```
+ (UIColor *) colorWithHex:(int)color {

    float red = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    float green = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    float blue = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    float alpha = (color & 0x000000ff);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0 green:green/255.0 blue:blue/255.0 alpha:alpha/255.0];
}
```

easy to use like this

```
[UIColor colorWithHex:0xFF0000FF]; //Red
[UIColor colorWithHex:0x00FF00FF]; //Green
[UIColor colorWithHex:0x00FF00FF]; //Blue
[UIColor colorWithHex:0x0000007F]; //transparent black
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a convenience init for that:

```
extension UIColor {
convenience init(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat)
{
    let redH = CGFloat(strtoul(hex.substringToIndex(advance(hex.startIndex,2)), nil, 16))
    let greenH = CGFloat(strtoul(hex.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(hex.startIndex, 2), end: advance(hex.startIndex, 4))), nil, 16))
    let blueH = CGFloat(strtoul(hex.substringFromIndex(advance(hex.startIndex,4)), nil, 16))

    self.init(red: redH/255, green: greenH/255, blue: blueH/255, alpha: alpha)
}
}
```

then you can create an UIColor anywhere in your project just like this:

```
UIColor(hex: "ffe3c8", alpha: 1)
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

You can create extension class of UIColor as:-

extension UIColor {

// MARK: -  getColorFromHex
    /**
    This function will convert the color Hex code to RGB.

```
- parameter color  hex string.

- returns: RGB color code.
*/
class func getColorFromHex(hexString:String)->UIColor{

    var rgbValue : UInt32 = 0
    let scanner:NSScanner =  NSScanner(string: hexString)

    scanner.scanLocation = 1
    scanner.scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

For swift 2.0+. 
This code works fine to me.

```
extension UIColor {
    /// UIColor(hexString: "#cc0000")
    internal convenience init?(hexString:String) {
        guard hexString.characters[hexString.startIndex] == Character("#") else {
            return nil
        }
        guard hexString.characters.count == "#000000".characters.count else {
            return nil
        }
        let digits = hexString.substringFromIndex(hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
        guard Int(digits,radix:16) != nil else{
            return nil
        }
        let red = digits.substringToIndex(digits.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
        let green = digits.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: digits.startIndex.advancedBy(2),
            end: digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4)))
        let blue = digits.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start:digits.startIndex.advancedBy(4),
            end:digits.startIndex.advancedBy(6)))
        let redf = CGFloat(Double(Int(red, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        let greenf = CGFloat(Double(Int(green, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        let bluef = CGFloat(Double(Int(blue, radix:16)!) / 255.0)
        self.init(red: redf, green: greenf, blue: bluef, alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    }
}
```

This code includes string format checking.
e.g.

```
let aColor = UIColor(hexString: "#dadada")!
let failed = UIColor(hexString: "123zzzz")
```

And as far as I know, my code is of no disadvantage for its maintaining the semantic of failible condition and returning an optional value. And this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.0 -  Xcode 7.2

**Adding an extension to UIColor.**

File -New - Swift File - Name it . Add the following.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString:String) {
        let hexString:NSString = hexString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        let scanner            = NSScanner(string: hexString as String)
        if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }

        var color:UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt(&color)

        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(color) & mask

        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1)
    }

    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
        return NSString(format:"#%06x", rgb) as String
    }        
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Ex. Setting Button's color from hexCode.
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        loginButton.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: " hex code here ")
}

Ex. Converting Button's current color to hex Code.

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let hexString = loginButton.tintColor.toHexString()
        print("HEX STRING: \(hexString)")

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2.0** version of solution which will handle alpha value of color and with perfect error handling is here:

```
func RGBColor(hexColorStr : String) -> UIColor?{

    var red:CGFloat = 0.0
    var green:CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue:CGFloat = 0.0
    var alpha:CGFloat = 1.0

    if hexColorStr.hasPrefix("#"){

        let index   = hexColorStr.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
        let hex     = hexColorStr.substringFromIndex(index)
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: hex)
        var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0

        if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexValue)
        {
            if hex.characters.count == 6
            {
                red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0
            }
            else if hex.characters.count == 8
            {
                red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
                green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
            }
            else
            {
                print("invalid hex code string, length should be 7 or 9", terminator: "")
                return nil
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("scan hex error")
       return nil
        }
    }

    let color: UIColor =  UIColor(red:CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue:CGFloat(blue), alpha: alpha)
    return color
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    //UIColorWithHexString

    static UIColor * UIColorWithHexString(NSString *hex) {
        unsigned int rgb = 0;
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:
          [[hex uppercaseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
           [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789ABCDEF"] invertedSet]]]
         scanHexInt:&rgb];
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0
                               green:((CGFloat)((rgb & 0xFF00) >> 8)) / 255.0
                                blue:((CGFloat)(rgb & 0xFF)) / 255.0
                               alpha:1.0];
    }
```

**Usage**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColorWithHexString(@"#0F35C0");
```

Answer (score 2):

UIColor Hex initialization

```
extension UIColor{
public  convenience init(hex : String) {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        self.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        return
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    self.init(
    red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
    green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
    blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
    alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}


//Iniitailization
let myColor = UIColor(hex: "#452b4e")
```

Happy coding ! Enjoy !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The most posted solutions uses `Scanner`, but you don't really need it at lease in the modern Swift. Instead you can simple use `UInt` init with radix 16 and then use basic binary operations to get `UIColor` components:

```
func stringToColor(color: String) -> UIColor {
    guard let i = UInt(color, radix: 16) else {
        return UIColor.white
    }
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((i & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((i & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(i & 0xFF) / 255.0,
        alpha: 1.0
    )
}
```

This solution expects input like "FF00FF", you may need to remove leading hash symbol (#) if you have one in your string.

Comment: What should `color` be in `UInt(color, radix: 16)`? It cannot be found in scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, the `color` actually a function parameter name, I fixed the code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(var hex: String) {
        hex = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString
        hex = (hex.hasPrefix("#")) ? hex.substringFromIndex(advance(hex.startIndex, 1)) : hex

        var value: UInt32 = 0
        if NSScanner(string: hex).scanHexInt(&value) {
            if count(hex) == 8 {
                self.init(red: CGFloat((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0,
                    green: CGFloat((value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                    blue: CGFloat((value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                    alpha: CGFloat((value & 0x000000FF)) / 255.0)
                return
            } else if count(hex) == 6 {
                self.init(red: CGFloat((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                    green: CGFloat((value & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                    blue: CGFloat(value & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
                    alpha: 1.0)
                return
            }
        }
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** This code will return `UIColor` from your hex color string

```
- (UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex  
{  
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];  

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters  
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];  

    // strip 0X if it appears  
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];  

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];  

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings  
    NSRange range;  
    range.location = 0;  
    range.length = 2;  
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

    range.location = 2;  
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

    range.location = 4;  
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

    // Scan values  
    unsigned int r, g, b;  
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];  
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];  
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];  

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)  
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)  
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)  
                           alpha:1.0f];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert hex color to RGB value using any converter website (if you google "hex to rgb", you'll see a ton). For example, this one: http://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/

Then change the color property to UIColor. Example:

```
self.profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:167 blue:142 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Hex color value was: 00a78e converted to RGB: R: 0 G: 167 B: 142

If the RGB values you are giving are not between 0 and 1.0, you'll have to divide them by 255. Example:

```
self.profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:83.00/255.0 green:123.00/255.0 blue:53.00/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Polished Extension from the original answer by @Tom
feel free to update the code [here](https://gist.github.com/bennagar/ef2a637e5aba3603bedb)

```
extension UIColor{
    convenience init (hexString:String) {
        var cleanString:String = hexString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

        if (cleanString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cleanString = cleanString.substringFromIndex(cleanString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
        }

        if (cleanString.characters.count != 6) {
            self.init()
        }
        else{
            var rgbValue = UInt32()
            let scanner = NSScanner(string: cleanString)
            scanner.scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

            self.init(
                red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0,
                green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0,
                blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0,
                alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but I think it really needs to return an optional UIColor, and check to see if scanHexInt fails (returns boolean).  If I pass in a HexString I'm not sure I want to get back some oddly defined UIColor that may have only had .init() called with no real values!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.0:**

Add this method to VC or to Extension of UIColor.

```
func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = (cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(1)
        }

        if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        }

        let rString = (cString as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
        let gString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
        let bString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)

        var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
        NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
        NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
        NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)


        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
    }
```

**Usage :**

```
    loginButton.tintColor = self.colorWithHexString("#be1337")

     OR

    let hexColor = self.colorWithHexString("#be1337")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library

https://github.com/burhanuddin353/TFTColor

Swift

```
UIColor.colorWithRGB(hexString: "FF34AE" alpha: 1.0)
```

Objective-C

```
[UIColor colorWithRGBHexString:@"FF34AE" alpha:1.0f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 example of [Ethan Strider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27203596/2108547). A function that takes a hex string and returns a UIColor.
*(You can enter hex strings with either format: `#ffffff` or `ffffff`)*

Example:

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString: String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        if let range = cString.range(of: cString) {
            cString = cString.substring(from: cString.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1))
        }
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
var color1 = hexStringToUIColor("#d3d3d3")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.iOS you can use the following instead of the macro:

```
public UIColor UIColorFromHexValue(int value, float alpha = 1f) =>
    UIColor.FromRGBA(
        ((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f,
        ((value & 0x00FF00) >> 16) / 255.0f,
        ((value & 0x0000FF) >> 16) / 255.0f,
        alpha);
```

The usage is analogous:

```
label.TextColor = UIColorFromHexValue(0xBC1128);
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting for reference a site I just found.
It does all the dirty job and, starting from HEX or RGB, prints out the code in ObjC, Swift and Xamarin.

https://www.uicolor.xyz/#/hex-to-ui

Answer (score 0):

[There is](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/html-colors/) a nice UIColor category with many features in it.

Usage:

```
textView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:textColorHex];
NSLog(@"Text Color Hex: %@", textColorHex);
```

Where textColorHex has a form of @"FFFFFF" without # symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Several above solutions involve somewhat unnecessary use of NSStrings. This UIColor class extension is bit simpler & faster:

```
+ colorWithHex:(UInt32)hex alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0
                           green:((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8)/255.0
                            blue:( hex & 0x0000FF)/255.0
                           alpha:alpha];
}
```

and to use it simply:

```
return [UIColor colorWithHex:0x006400 alpha:1.0]; // HTML darkgreen
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment helps nobody. So, <anonymous>, if you take issue with my specifically *not* using NSStrings, please note that by far-and-above the top-rated answer to this question, courtesy of Tom, does likewise. And IMHO a UIColor class extension is just a cleaner solution than a #define. The only possible reason I could think of needing to convert hex color codes *in an NSString* would be if you are trying to parse an HTML stream, at which point you should probably look into init'ing an NSAttributedString with a NSHTMLTextDocumentType, and let it tool handle *all* the markups.

Answer (score 0):

In swift I created a class extension with the following methods to convert a hex code to a UIColor.

```
extension UIColor {  
  convenience init(R: CGFloat, G: CGFloat, B: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
    self.init(red: R/255.0, green: G/255.0, blue: B/255.0, alpha: alpha)
  }

  class func colorWithHex(hex: UInt, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(R: CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16), G: CGFloat((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8), B: CGFloat(hex & 0x0000FF), alpha: alpha)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode's native [Color Literals feature](https://nshipster.com/swift-literals/) to add hex colors easily and natively.

Type `Color Literal` into your code and let Xcode autocomplete do the rest.

The color picker UI will allow you to paste in a Hex Color: `#FF9300`

[image: color picker]

The git diff of the macro will show RGB values rather than hex:

```
let orange = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

But it's still an easy way to paste in hex without any 3rd party tools or extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers use [`Scanner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner), bitmasks, or substring operations.

It's also possible to extract the color components using [`chunks(ofCount:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md) and [`UInt8.init(_:radix:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/init(_:radix:)):

```swift
import Foundation
import XCTest
import Algorithms

class UIColorFromStringTests: XCTestCase {
    func testUIColorFromString() throws {
        let color = "00FF00"
        let components = color
            .chunks(ofCount: 2)
            .compactMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
        XCTAssertEqual(components, [0x00, 0xFF, 0x00])
        let red = CGFloat(components[0]) / 255 // 0
        let green = CGFloat(components[1]) / 255 // 1
        let blue = CGFloat(components[2]) / 255 // 0
        _ = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```