# Objective-C parse hex string to integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, parsing, hex

I would like to know how to parse a hex string, representing a number, in Objective-C. I am willing to use both an objective, or a C-based method, either is fine.

example:

```
#01FFFFAB
```

should parse into the integer:
    33554347

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Joshua Weinberg's answer is mostly correct, however the `0x` prefix is optional when scanning hexadecimal integers. If you have a string in the format `#01FFFFAB`, you can still use  `NSScanner`, but you can skip the first character.

```
unsigned result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"#01FFFFAB"];

[scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
```

Comment: Note that if you want to perform strict parsing, you should first check that the string does not begin with `0x` (or `0X`). NSScanner will accept those prefixes.

Answer (score 65):

you can use [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this

```
unsigned int outVal;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x01FFFFAB"];
[scanner scanHexInt:&outVal];
```

`outVal` will contain the int you're looking for. The 0x is optional.

Comment: In addition, you could use a string substitution to convert the # character to the 0x prefix.

Comment: should be unsigned int outVal;

Answer (score 12):

strtol() is your friend.

It converts a string to a long, and you can pass the base of the number in. Strip that # sign off first though, or pass to strtol a pointer to the first numerical character.

Comment: I'm going with this method, way simpler (and potentially quicker) than allocating an nsscanner.

Comment: @Chris: It's probably no quicker if you have an NSString, because you'd need to convert the NSString to a C string before you can use strtol. If you already have the text in a C string, it will probably be faster, but unless you are doing this thousands or millions of times I doubt you'd feel the performance hit.

Comment: int res = strtol( [yourString UTF8String], NULL, base)

Comment: @dreamlax The definition of -[NSString UTF8String] shows that it returns a pointer to the backing UTF8 C string (NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER). At a high level, it's only a single operation to return this const char pointer versus the overhead of allocating memory for NSScanner, copying the NSString input parameter, not to mention the additional ObjC message-passing latency incurred with each ObjC method invocation. It's algorithmically much faster to use strtoull(), but you likely won't observe the difference unless you're benchmarking scanning hex integers from millions of strings :-)

Comment: @Jacob: `NSString` objects are stored as UTF-16, not UTF-8 (as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)), so conversion to UTF-8 is first required (which is potentially costly), whereas the `NSScanner` *may* be optimised for UTF-16. The `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER` is an annotation that extends the lifetime of an object until the last use of the returned pointer (or any pointer derived from it). See [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#interior-pointers). It's for ARC / GC.

Comment: The `strtol` function is also a lot more lenient. Write thorough unit tests (include spaces, non-hex characters, etc..) as you will find some surprising edge cases that `NSScanner` gives you more control over.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below line for conversion. Its just one line code:

```
NSString *hexString = @"01FFFFAB";
length = (UInt64)strtoull([hexString UTF8String], NULL, 16);
NSLog(@"The required Length is %d", length);
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Note that if you want to perform strict parsing, you should first check that the string does not begin with `0x` (or `0X`) or +/- or any other characters that are not considered valid in your input.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** standard library introduced new initializer for parsing all integer types. It takes string to parse with radix (i.e. base) and returns optional integer:

```
let number = Int("01FFFFAB", radix: 16)!
```

Comment: @MZaragoza I added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

According to apple:

> An NSScanner object interprets and converts the characters of an
>   NSString object into number and string values.

so, if u have `NSData` obj u can do next

```
NSString *dataDescription = data.description;
NSString *dataAsString = [dataDescription substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [dataDescription length]-2)];
unsigned intData = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:dataAsString];
[scanner scanHexInt:&intData];
```

Comment: Note that if you want to perform strict parsing, you should first check that the string does not begin with `0x` (or `0X`) or any other characters that are not considered valid in your input, but which are accepted by NSScanner.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
var hex = "#01FFFFAB"
hex.remove(at: hex.startIndex)
var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)
// rgbValue == 33554347
```