# How to get an int in decimal from a Hex NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to get a dec value from a Hex-encoded string, 
for examples: A->10, B->11,etc.
and I coded as the following

```
NSString *tempNumber;
tempNumber=number.text; 
NSScanner *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:tempNumber];
unsigned int temp;
[scanner scanHexInt:temp];
NSLog(@"%@:%d",tempNumber,temp);
```

but the NSLog output isn't what I perfer..

```
2012-01-24 01:34:57.703 TestingUnit[34861:f803] 4:-1073750472
2012-01-24 01:35:01.133 TestingUnit[34861:f803] 6:-1073750408
2012-01-24 01:35:01.983 TestingUnit[34861:f803] 2:-1073750408
2012-01-24 01:35:02.414 TestingUnit[34861:f803] 1:-1073750408
```

could someone tell me how can I solve this????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C parse hex string to integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use

```
[scanner scanHexInt:&temp];
```

`scanHexInt:` expects a pointer, not a value.