# Objective-C, How to properly encode hex to image file?

Tags: objective-c, image, hex

I have a method in my app that I would like to write hex values into a file (essentially creating an image from the written bytes). I can't seem to figure out how to encode the values properly to produce the image. Any suggestion would be appreciated - thanks.

```
- (void)makeImage {

@autoreleasepool {

    NSString* hexValues = @"8950..." // these are the hex bytes that make up the image file

    NSString* fileName    = @"image.png";
    NSString* homeDir     = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop/"];

    NSString* fullPath = [homeDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSError* error = nil;
    [lastLine writeToFile:fullPath atomically:NO encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

}
```

Comment: You're basic problem is that your "hexValues" object isn't -- it's a string with characters in it that look like hex values when printed.  Not clear why/how you'd get the bits of an image in that form, but if that's what you have, you need to convert each pair of "hex" characters into one 8-bit byte, using one of the techniques discussed below.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the NSString in an NSData with lossy ASCII encoding or UTF-8, then you can use the method -[NSData bytes] to get to the raw bytes.

Use a for loop to loop through them 2 bytes at a time, you can then either copy the two bytes/characters you are upto into a char array of of size 3 (3 to include the \0, make sure you initialize it with "00" to get a terminating \0) you can then use the c function

```
long int strtol ( const char * str, char ** endptr, int base );
```

to convert the two bytes/hex to an integer.

Alternatively you can write your own hex-string to int that doesn't require a terminating \0.

Comment: If you want to use a object-oriented method, NSScanner is a good approach. Also see this question: [Objective-C - Parse hex string to integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer)

Comment: @Nathan, hi thanks for the answer — how would i write my own hex-string to int?

Comment: covert each character into a int by using c-'0' for digits or c-'A' for uppercase. you will then have two int, one and two, to convert into a single byte value use (one<<4)+two;