# How can I convert my transparent PNG image to a Hexadecimal string?

Tags: ios, image, encoding, hex, converters

Within an SDK that I'm using within one of my apps there are some images. These images are not just listed as image files but as hexedecimal encoded strings like:

```
unsigned char MASTCloseButton_png[] = {
  0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d,
  0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38,
  0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa8, 0x86, 0x3b, 0x1e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x09, 0x70, 0x48, 0x59, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x23, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2e,
  0x23, 0x01, 0x78, 0xa5, 0x3f, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x69, 0x43,
};
```

No I'd like to adjust this image within this SDK but unfortunately I don't know how to convert my .png file into a hexadecimal string as listed above.

Are there any tools to convert my .png image (with transparency) to a hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image)];
NSString *imageStr = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:imageData];
```

**OR follow:**

http://kelp.phate.org/2012/05/high-performance-hex-encode-in.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309158/objective-c-how-to-properly-encode-hex-to-image-file