# nsstring to unsigned char []

Tags: objective-c, c

I would convert

```
NSString *myString = @"0x10 0x1c 0x37 0x00"; //Aquired reading text file using NSString methods..
```

to

```
unsigned char convertedfrommyString[] = { 0x10, 0x1c, 0x37, 0x00 };
```

My goal is to aquiring them and then swap it using this code:

```
unsigned char convertedfrommyString[] = { 0x10, 0x1c, 0x37, 0x00 };
    int data = *((int *) convertedfromString);
    NSLog(@"log = %08x", data);
```

the output should be:

```
log = 00371c10
```

Any help?

EDIT

From both Jan Baptiste Younès and Sven I found the way to understand my problem and solve  with this code:

```
NSString *myString = [[@"0x10 0x1c 0x37 0x00" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0x" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    unsigned result = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];
    int reverse = NSSwapInt(result);
    NSLog(@"scanner: %8u", result);
    NSLog(@"bytes:%08x", result);
    NSLog(@"reverse:%08x (that is what i need!)", reverse);
```

Really OK!
But can I accept two answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may cut your original string at spaces and use the solution given here [Objective-C parse hex string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer). You can also use `scanUpToString:intoString` to parse upto space chars.

Comment: like *myString = @"101c3700" and then what? :)

Comment: No construct the scanner with `scannerWithString`, `scanUpToString:@" " intoString:aNumberString` and then convert `aNumberString` variable into int with another scanner and `scanNexInt:@myInt`

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I found the way to do what I need from your suggestion but also from Sven answer...

Comment: You can also use `sscanf` from the data extracted with `getCString:` methods

Answer (score 2):

That's more than a simple conversion, you need to actually parse the values from your string. You can use NSScanner to do this.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: @"0x10 0x1c 0x37 0x00"];
unsigned char convertedfrommyString[4];
unsigned index = 0;
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    unsigned value = 0;
    if (![scanner scanHexInt: &value]) {
        // invalid value
        break;
    }

    convertedfrommyString[index++] = value;
}
```

Of course this sample is missing error handling (the single values could not fit into an unsigned char or there could be more than four).

But this solved only half your problem. The other issue is converting this to an int. You did this by casting the unsigned char pointer to an int pointer. This is not portable and also not legal in C. To always get the result you want you should instead use bit shifts to  assemble your int. So inside your loop you could do

```
result = result | (value << i);
i += 8;
```

instead of putting the values inside an unsigned char array. For this `result` and `i` should both be initialized to zero.

Comment: Ok i found the way, in a more simple way... who should I give credit to the new code?