# Convert NSString to Unsigned Short in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, swift, nsstring

I have `NSString` "3265" and i have to send this to a method in function in '`.c`' file has a parameter `unsigned short`

here my code..

In `.c` file

```
bool checkData(unsigned short num) {

}
```

In `.swift` file

```
var number: NSString! = "3265"
```

i need to send '`0x3265`' to `checkData` function.

How can i convert `3265`(`NSString`) to `0x3265`(`unsigned short`)

Comment: Are you sure that this is C++?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/intValue

Comment: @HotLicks Judging from the link that you posted, I am nearly certain that you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I see.  Well, the OP said nothing about hex encoding data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// This number is hex, not decimal (although it looks decimal)
let str = "3265"
// Hence we must parse it as a base-16 number:
let num : CUnsignedShort = CUnsignedShort(strtoul(str, nil, 16))
// Convert it back to hex for printing
println(String(num, radix:16)) // This should produce 3265
```

The call of `strtoul` converts the string to a number, interpreting it as hex. Then you make an `CUnsignedShort` from it, which you can pass to your C function.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *numberString = @"42";
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:numberString];
short numberShort = [number shortValue];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSScanner to convert `NSString` hexadecimals into `int`s:

```
int myVal;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:number];
[scanner scanHexInt:&myVal];
bool myBool = scanData((unsigned short)myVal);
```

Obviously this is objective-c but you should be able to do this in swift no problems.

It might be an idea to set myVal to -1 and then check that it is `>= 0` before sending it to the `scanData()` function to make sure no errors have occurred.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer).

Comment: You are passing the address of an `unsigned short` to a function expecting the address of an `int`. This can cause a crash or any kind of undefined behavior.