# How to scan hex integers, plural?

Tags: objective-c, hex

I want to parse multiple hex integers from a space-separated string of up to 20 numbers:

```
79 1A 03 00 09 21 22 AA BB CC DD EE FF A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7

unsigned result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"79 1A 03 00"];

[scanner setScanLocation:0];
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
```

But scanHexInt seems to only scan a single value.  Is there a cleaner way to scan a string into an array of values?

[scanHexInt docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanHexInt:)

[Objective-C parse hex string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648411/objective-c-parse-hex-string-to-integer)

Comment: Use a loop to scan each value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSArray *numberTokens = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];
  for (NSString* token in numberTokens) {
    if (0 < token.length) {
      NSLog(@"%@: %i", token, token.intValue);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Simpler to use `[text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];`

Comment: `NSString intValue` won't parse hex values. It only works with decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use most of the code you already have, simply adjust the `scanLocation` in a loop:

```
NSString *string = @"79 1A 03 00 09 21 22 AA BB CC DD EE FF A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7";
unsigned result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

// Skip ahead 3 characters (2 hex digits + 1 space)
// after each iteration.
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < string.length; i+=3) {
    [scanner setScanLocation:i];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&result];

    NSLog(@"%d", result);
}
```