# Hex color value in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have hex value in mind that I need to implement, working on ipad by the way. Anyways, how can I go about implementing that with objective-c

Help much needed, pleas and thank you!

Answer (score 22):

UIColor's range is from 0 to 1. So you just need to convert the hex color string into decimal, then divide by 255 to get the desired numbers.

For example, if the color is `#E0EAF1`:

1. Convert hex to decimal: `E0` → 224, `EA` → 234, `F1` → 241
2. Divide by 255: 224  → 0.878, 234 → 0.918, 241 → 0.945

So to create this color, use

```
UIColor* clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.878f green:0.918f blue:0.945f alpha:1];
```

or let the compiler do the calculation for you:

```
UIColor* clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xE0/255.0f
                               green:0xEA/255.0f
                                blue:0xF1/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I also found a very useful macro that allows your to simply input the hex with the method call.

Comment: Here you go! :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string