# How to convert from a hex value to a UIColor?

Tags: iphone, colors, hex, uicolor, cgcolor

I have a hexadecimal color value and I want to convert it to a UIColor.  UIColor can take in a Hue/Saturation/Brightness (HSB) value or a Red/Blue/Green (RGB) value.  How can I use the hex value to create a UIColor?

Comment: Hex is a number base, while HSB is a color space... it's like asking how to convert cursive to Italian. Are you asking how to convert an RGB hex value to HSB?

Answer (score 2):

There is a great free library that is basically just some add ons to UIColor [here](https://github.com/erica/uicolor-utilities) (i think this is the same thing I use, cant remember).  Check it out to make sure, but I think it has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Picked this up from somewhere a while back, it's been sitting in my macro header for all my projects for a while now.

To use: view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2134b6)

```
//RGB color macro
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

//RGB color macro with alpha
#define UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(rgbValue,a) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:a]
```

Comment: I don't see the HSB conversion here, did you include everything you meant to in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to [How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string/7180905#7180905)

The basic concept is to take the red blue green segments of the hex string, divide them by 256, and there you have your [0, 1] red blue green values that UIColor needs.

Forget the HSB values, you don't need to make that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your color value is encoded in the HEX value. But here's an example with RGB values. Let's say you have a HEX value encoded something like this hexRGB = 0xRRGGBB to assign it to a UIColor, all you would have to do is

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(hexRGB & 0xFF0000 >> 16) green:(hexRGB & 0x00FF00 >> 8) blue:(hexRGB & 0x0000FF) alpha:1]
```

The same technique could be used if reading a HSB value from hex where the value is encoded: 0xHHSSBB

Comment: Don't forget to divide it by 255

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned your HEX values are probably RGB.

I needed to do this once for a method I found that created button highlights programmatically. The theory behind HSB (or HSV as it is also known) is discussed in great detail at [wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) All the mathematics of the color space is there so if implementing your own it's probably the place to start.

There's a nice, compact, simple implementation in C at [Rochester Institute of Technology.](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) You should be able to paste these functions in and use them directly.

(But if Erica Sadun wrote a category to provide this function in UIColor, use it. See Jesse Naugher's answer for link.)