# Changing text color using my own color in iphone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I want to change all my text color with my own colorcode value(#003366).

I know this about it-

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but instead of white color I want #003366 (blue)

How to do it in iphone?

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6207329/294661

Comment: please learn how to use google and/or search @stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//would be pale red
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.8f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this code as macro,

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

and then

```
myLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x003366);
```

Comment: how can I change color of text on button with my color(0*003366)

Comment: @python : `[btn setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x003366) forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

I edited the macro,remove semicolon from end of that define code.

Comment: Thanks iApple.I got the result.