# Why! 100% Cyan in CMYK is NOT rgb(0,255,255)? in Photoshop

Tags: colors, rgb, photoshop, cmyk

I try to convert a solid cyan to RGB in photoshop. But I get confuse about the RGB values "rgb(0, 160, 233)".

Where can i find the formula or icc profile to calculate RGB values that like Photoshop.

Comment: This converts hex colors to UIColors http://stackoverflow.com/a/32518747/3681880 Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: CMYK has a completely different colour gamut to RGB.

Answer (score 2):

There is not one conversion which is "right" - it depends on the colour profiles you are using.

For instance, it could be the case that your CMYK Cyan is outside of the sRGB colour space - in that case Photoshop tries to get as close as possible to the right colour, but it stays within the RGB-values that are possible for this profile. Don't wonder if other programs calculate other RGB-values.

But if you change to ProPhoto RGB colour space, it may be possible to match your Cyan much better, as this colour space is much larger. So, of course, the RGB values are different again.

For more information, see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5138/why-are-colors-shifting-when-converting-from-cmyk-to-rgb-in-photoshop