# UITabBar title hexa value

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to set hexa decimal value (particular color value) for UITabBar title. I know the below the code for normal. I need to set hexadecimal value instead of blue color. If i need to set #33223 means what can i do?

```
 [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor :[UIColor colorWithRed:5 green:112 blue:180 alpha:2]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This might help you with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207329/how-to-set-hex-color-code-for-background

Comment: I'm asking how to use hexa decimal value for UITabBar title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate the hexa color to Rgb and use `[UIColor colorWithRed:200 green:191 blue:231 alpha:1]`

Comment: It's not working. See edited code what i did. Same white color only displaying.

Comment: why it's not taking custom RGB value color?

Comment: it should take custom color. sry It should be floats. so 200/255.0f and so one would make it work. So #008000 = gree, UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:128/255.0 blue:0/255.0f alpha:1] This should give you a green color. I only get black color for your hex #33223.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIColor *)getUIColorObjectFromHexString:(NSString *)hexStr alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
  // Convert hex string to an integer
  unsigned int hexint = [self intFromHexString:hexStr];

  // Create color object, specifying alpha as well
  UIColor *color =
    [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255
    green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255
    blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255
    alpha:alpha];

  return color;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *hexStr1 = @"123ABC";
UIColor *color1 = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:hexStr1 alpha:.9];
NSLog(@"UIColor: %@", color1);
```