# How to change a hex color code depending on the time in IOS

Tags: ios, hex

I would like to have the background of an app change colour depending on the time, for example if it is 12:34:56 the hex color code would be #123456 so the background would change color to #123456. Is this possible. Also is there any way to could use broader numbers and letters possibly because the format could exclude a lot colours.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set hex color code for background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207329/how-to-set-hex-color-code-for-background)

Comment: @Mrunal This is different because it asking for changing the code based on a variable

Comment: Half of reddit is currently making an app like this ;)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Haha yeah, I'm just doing this for experience though.

Comment: @MichaelByrne Did you find relative answer as you required?

Answer (score 0):

to set hex color you can refer to: [how to set hex color code for background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207329/how-to-set-hex-color-code-for-background)
to change it every second - just create specific parser, using `NSDateFormatter:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hhmmss"]; //hours minutes seconds
```

and then put it into function and call it every seconds using `NSTimer`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeBackgroundColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Referring the answer from duplicate question suggested)

Try this code:

```
NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hhmmss"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:mydate];
```

Then I would use

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:formattedDateString ]];
```

Now `colorWithHexString` method is given in this question link: [how to set hex color code for background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207329/how-to-set-hex-color-code-for-background)

Hope this helps you to achieve your requirements.