# Change navigation bar text color and status bar icons to white

Tags: ios

I've succeeded setting the background color of the navigation bar to black.
In the AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    [navigationBarAppearance setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

Is there a way to set the navigation bar title and the icons in the status bar to white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the navigation bar:

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yourColor};
```

or, using appearances

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yourColor}];
```

If you want the status bar to be white throughout your entire application, set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in Info.plist. After that, do the following in your app delegate

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Apparently `setStatusBarStyle:` has been deprecated in iOS 9, so use `preferredStatusBarStyle` instead. To do this, add the following to each of your view controllers

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: I'm using `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: whiteColor}];` and I get a `Use of undeclared identifier` error on the whiteColor

Comment: Try `[UIColor whiteColor]` instead.

Comment: It's working for the navigation bar. It's also working with icons in the status bar but it says that `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated

Comment: It's working now. I'd like to ask you another question. Can I change  blackColor and use a #00cc00 format?

Comment: I personally don't know all that much about using hex values in iOS, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207457/1702077) seems as though it would help you.