# Issue with colour of Custom Snackbar action button

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I need to change the colour of the action button in Snackbar with a colour that is not pre-defined by Android studio (ie. without using `Color.BLUE`, etc).

I have researched on this question in Google/stack overflow. But so far all the tutorials out there only uses default values. But I would like to use hex values (eg. `#a1b2c3`)

Thus, I would like to know if this is possible. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207329/how-to-set-hex-color-code-for-background this may help u

Comment: @yagneshdobariya The link you mentioned is for Xcode

Comment: Well that's x-code... I'm looking for Java / Android...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the custom color using the below line

```
 snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a1b2c3"));
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
snackBar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

<s>getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)</s>
is deprecated by android you have to use the **ContextCompat**

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```

[Check this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated)

**color.xml**

```
<color name="colorAccent">#607d8b</color>
```