# change text color in table view using # iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i'm trying to change the text color for my cells using the # like you do in Android xml for example: `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor #E01B4C];` that way i can get whatever color i desire.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/iphone-change-hex-color-format-to-uicolor

Comment: Great :) And whats your question?

Comment: Yes better you refer the link posted by @Krypton and delete this post.

Comment: @Nitish, You really don't understand what he is looking for?

Comment: @AndrewS The highest-rated answer there does precisely what the user asked for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3532264/766441

Comment: Oops yes your right, I read this as how to change the text colour of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

UIColor has no such method to convert hex color, you should convert yourself:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(float)0xe0/0xff green:(float)0x1b/0xff blue:(float)0x4c/0xff alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: and how can i know which hex value ´0xe0/0xff´ has?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this getColor method and passing hexdecimal value as an argument

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [self getColor:E01B4C];
```

then make this method.

```
- (UIColor *) getColor: (NSString *) hexColor//method for converting hexadecimal into colors.
    {
        unsigned int red, green, blue;//declaring colors of unsigned int type.

        NSRange range;//range

        range.length = 2;//length of range.

        range.location = 0; //location of range.

        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&red];//scannig red color.

        range.location = 2;//location of red.

        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&green];//scanning green color.

        range.location = 4;//location of green.

        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&blue];//scanning blue color. 

        return [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)(red/255.0f) green:(float)(green/255.0f) blue:(float)(blue/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];//returning customized colors.
    }
```