# HEX value in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor

I want to create UIColor from HEX value. But my Color is a NSString. So i implement this solution:
[How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string)

code:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

And then i have (simplify):

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0xFFFFFF"];
```

So when i want to call macro:

```
UIColor *myColor = UIColorFromRGB(myString);
```

I'm getting an error: `invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'int')`

So i know i have to pass int, but how to convert NSString to int in this case? Of course `[myString intValue];` does not work here.

Comment: By the way, you made an error in the masking values of the code you copied. Green should be (rgbValue & 0x00FF00), not (rgbValue & 0xFF00), and blue should be (rgbValue & 0x0000FF), not (rgbValue & 0xFF). I copied your code, and had quite a time figuring out the problem. Anyway, I learned a lot about bitwise shifting and adding from Doug Galante at https://medium.com/@Dougly/bitwise-shifting-swift-3-a85a6954fb05

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can either use your macro directly with hex integers like this:

```
UIColorFromRGB(0xff4433)
```

Or you can parse the hex-string into an integer like this:

```
unsigned colorInt = 0;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString] scanHexInt:&colorInt];
UIColorFromRGB(colorInt)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that as standard but check out my [category on `UIColor`](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Categories/UIColor/UIColor-MJGAdditions.m) which has a method for doing that.

Your macro you've defined is expecting that to be an integer packed in RGB format. You're passing in a string, which is why it's not working.