# iOS: Custom color as UILabel background color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Is there some way to assign #334433 as UILabel background color?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method:

```
- (UIColor *) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) hex
{  
     NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];  

     // String should be 6 or 8 characters  
     if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];  

     // strip 0X if it appears  
     if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];  

     if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];  

     // Separate into r, g, b substrings  
     NSRange range;  
     range.location = 0;  
     range.length = 2;  
     NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

     range.location = 2;  
     NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

     range.location = 4;  
     NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];  

     // Scan values  
     unsigned int r, g, b;  
     [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];  
     [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];  
     [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];  

     return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)  
                       green:((float) g / 255.0f)  
                        blue:((float) b / 255.0f)  
                       alpha:1.0f];  
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
[self colorWithHexString:@"334433"]
```

Comment: interesting meth. Looks like I will use it right now. Response accepted (After 5 min.)