# html color code to uicolor

Tags: html, uiwebview, colors, uicolor

In an UIWebview, I load a html page whose background color is #CBCDCF.
In the previous ViewController (in this ViewController I don't use UIWebview), I want to set the background color to the same value: #CBCDCF. How can I do it?

Comment: No. To set color for uiview, I intended to use [self.view setBackgroundColor:anUIColor]; To initialize anUIColor, I see no method to initialize it with a color code such as #CBCDCF.

Comment: It'will be interesting to know if my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro like this

```
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                    green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                     blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 \
                                    alpha:1.0]
```

and you can do this :

```
[yourViewController setBackgroundColor:HEXCOLOR(0xCBCDCF)]
```

Comment: This macro does not work for me, I've found a right one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string