# How can I convert mystring to UIcolor type so i can change label color with selected color from tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(afterClick:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];

-(void)afterClick:(UIColor *)viewColor{
    lblColor.backgroundColor=viewColor;

}
```

Instead of UIColor I want to pass string, please suggest

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/a/19072934/2122979 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string)

Comment: @Seema Do you want to create a color from hex string or some random string?

Comment: @Seema does your code not work? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @ Damir179: with random string

Answer (score 0):

```
#define UICOLOR_FROM_HEX(hex, alpha) [UIColor colorWithRed: ((float)((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green: ((float)((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue: ((float)(hex & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha: alpha]
```

Used:

```
self.backgroundColor = UICOLOR_FROM_HEX(0xFFEECC, 1.0);
```