# BMI calculator compiler error swift

Tags: xcode, swift

```
var BMIValue = (WeightTextField*703)/(HeightTextField*HeightTextField)
```

My error:

> Cannot invoke '/' with an argument list of type '(($T5), ($T11))'

I had made an attempt on making a simple **BMI** calculator however this function that I have typed out constantly brings compiler errors. Can someone please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: what are those: `WeightTextField` and `HeightTextField`?

Comment: those are the user input for height and weight

Comment: You need to convert text to number

Comment: @roshan, are those `UITextField` instances?

Comment: thanks  , i have one last question , must I assign the input provided as WeightTextField.text or just plain WeightTextField

Comment: @holex , yes they are

Comment: @roshan, is it not yet suspicious multiplying and dividing `UITextField` instances to you...? you have to convert their `text` value to number for doing arithmetical operands...

Comment: @holex , i don't really understand , could you explain in a bit more simpler terms to me. I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: @roshan, if you are newbie, first you need to read more about `UITextField`, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html and converting string to number, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085665/convert-string-to-float-in-apples-swift

Comment: @holex , i tried doing what is shown in the answer but i get a new problem , the code breaks at abc.toInt()!

Comment: Do you know what to do in this case , also , while running the app in the simulator , the app freezes after i click the button

Answer (score 0):

This solution , converts UITextfields text into Floats and then assign BMI value to another float variable.

```
var weight = (WeightlTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
var height = (HeightTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
var BMIValue = (weight*703)/height
```

Hope this helps .