# Why is my variable returning a nil after being converted to an int?

Tags: swift

I'm taking data from an api and storing it in a string variable. When I print the variable it returns what I'm looking for but when I try to convert it to an int using the .toInt method it returns a nil?

```
func getWeather() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
            var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("temperature value=\"")
            var temperatureString = (urlContentArray[1].substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length:6))) as String
            println(temperatureString) // returns 272.32
            var final = temperatureString.toInt()
            println(final) //returns nil
            println(temperatureString.toInt())
            self.temperature.text = "\(temperatureString)"
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even simpler, though slightly a trick, you can use `integerValue`:

```
temperatureString.integerValue
```

Unlike `toInt`, `integerValue` will stop converting when it finds a non-digit (it also throws away leading spaces.

If `temperatureString` is a `String` (rather than an `NSString`), you'll need to push it over:

```
(temperatureString as NSString).integerValue
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Believe it or not, I just had this bug tonight converting some C code to Swift (and my toInt call failed for the same reason). So I happened to have just researched it…

Answer (score 1):

That's because 272.32 is not an integer.

You could [convert it to a Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085665/convert-string-to-float-in-apples-swift).

Comment: Even so, wouldn't it just drop the decimal points and store it as 272?

Comment: Nope you're absolutely right, I just checked and 252 returns the value while any float returns a nil. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`272.32` isn't an Integer. If your temperature string is an `NSString`, you can do this to convert it:

```
Int("272.32".floatValue)
```