# Swift Programming cannot convert to float

Tags: swift

Attached is my code, it is basically two text boxes being added together, however I do not know how to handle float variables.  Any help is appreciated

```
@IBOutlet weak var first: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var second: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!

@IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {

   total.text = "\(first.text.toInt()!+second.text.toInt()!)"
```

Comment: I don't see any float variables here.

Comment: He's trying to get total.text in a Float value instead of the toInt() part.

Comment: "\\(first.text.toInt() ?? 0 + second.text.toInt() ?? 0)"

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
let firstFloatValue = (first?.text as NSString).floatValue
let secondFloatValue = (second?.text as NSString).floatValue
```

and then,

```
total.text = "\(firstFloatValue + secondFloatValue)
```

Or any one of the many techniques mentioned in [Convert String to float in Apple's Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085665/convert-string-to-float-in-apples-swift)

Comment: No Go - get the error that 'String?' is not convertible to NSString