# NSCoreData - Textfield into float value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to add my textfield into the coredata as an float value, when user press a submit button. I have an error

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x1)

My attributes inside `.xcdatamodel` file and `NSManagedObject` class are set to type float.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var forceEntered: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var stiffnessEntered: UITextField!


 @IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let contxt : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("SpringVariables", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
        var newItem = SpringModel(entity:en!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

        newItem.stiffness = (stiffnessEntered.text as NSString).floatValue //error message shows here.
        newItem.force = (forceEntered.text as NSString).floatValue


 }
```

Comment: try `NSString(string: stiffnessEntered.text).floatValue`

Comment: @FrequencyMatched same error occurs.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24088249)

Comment: `(stiffnessEntered.text as NSString).floatValue` works when using prepareforsegue to pass my data between views previously. It doesn't work now when i want to add it into CoreData. @FrequencyMatched

Comment: Would need to see ManagedObject Class for 'SpringVariables' entity and probably full stack-trace of error

Comment: You are getting a bad access so something is `nil` that you were not expecting to be `nil`.  Everywhere you are forcing an entity you need to check for `nil` first.  Something is unexpectedly `nil`.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra  Thanks guys. I found the problem is because i didn't reference the entity to the class in the datamodel.