# xcode: need to convert strings to double and back to string

Tags: xcode, swift, double

this is my line of code.

```
budgetLabel.text = String((budgetLabel.text)!.toInt()! - (budgetItemTextBox.text)!.toInt()!)
```

the code works, but when I try to input a floating value into the textbox the program crashes. I am assuming the strings need to be converted to a float/double data type. I keep getting errors when i try to do that.

Comment: ofcours it crashes. Look at all your force-wraps. Stop doing that!

Comment: Use safe casts instead, e.g. "if let a = as? Int, b = as? Int" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Swift 2** there are new failable initializers that allow you to do this in more safe way, the `Double("")` returns an optional in cases like passing in `"abc"` string the failable initializer will return `nil`, so then you can use `optional-binding` to handle it like in the following way:

```
let s1 = "4.55"
let s2 = "3.15"

if let n1 = Double(s1), let n2 = Double(s2) {
   let newString = String( n1 - n2)
   print(newString)
}
else {
  print("Some string is not a double value")
}
```

If you're using a version of **Swift < 2**, then old way was:

```
var n1 = ("9.99" as NSString).doubleValue  // invalid returns 0, not an optional. (not recommended)

// invalid returns an optional value (recommended)
var pi = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("3.14")?.doubleValue
```

Comment: Thank you it's giving me an error, "Cannot find an initalizer of type double that accepts an argument of type string"

Comment: What version of Swift you're using?

Comment: @asmcriminal See updated answer to know the old way in previous version of Swift

Comment: I checked my xcode it says "version 6.4" i checked on google and 6.4 supposedly runs swift 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: Added Proper Handling for Optionals

```
let budgetLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
let budgetItemTextBox:UITextField = UITextField()
budgetLabel.text = ({
     var value = ""
     if let budgetString = budgetLabel.text, let budgetItemString = budgetItemTextBox.text
     {
          if let budgetValue = Float(budgetString), let budgetItemValue = Float(budgetItemString)
          {
               value = String(budgetValue - budgetItemValue)
          }
     }
     return value
})()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. it would give me a compiler error.  "binary operator '-' cannot be applied to 2 float operands"

Comment: Xcode always suggests using `!`. It is never ok, Xcode is always wrong

Comment: @RMenke okay, what is "unwrapping" and what are my "optionals?" I am a C++ programmer, recently trying to learn swift.

Comment: `optionals` are declared with either `!` or `?` behind the type. `var myOptional : String? = nil` Force unwrapping is using the variable with `!` which does not check for `nil` and crashes your app when so. Optional binding is using an `if let` to unwrap it. Google all those words.

Comment: @RMenke okay thanks. I did come across optional and unwrapping, but I didn't fully understand it. You explained it better than my professor. I get it now.

Comment: @RMenke fixed to not use forced unwrapping

Comment: okay i see it, now it's giving me an error "if let budgetValue = (budgetString), let budgetItemValue = Float(budgetItemString)"  Cannot find an initializer for type float

Comment: @asmcriminal are you using Swift 2 or 1.x?

Comment: @asmcriminal I believe `Float(string:)` initializer  was added in Swift 2.0, for Swift 1.x see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085665/convert-string-to-float-in-apples-swift

Comment: @asmcriminal Stop using old versions of Swift! Migration only becomes more of a pain if you wait longer. Swift 1.2 is dead buried and forgotten

Comment: @RMenke The issue is i have to update the entire OS to support the swift version I don't know much about macs. not sure if i have to reformat or how it all works. This semester is over, so I am done with swift for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `if let`. In swift 2.0 it would look something like this:

```
if let
    budgetString:String = budgetLabel.text,
    budgetItemString:String = budgetItemTextBox.text,
    budget:Double = Double(budgetString),
    budgetItem:Double = Double(budgetItemString) {
        budgetLabel.text = String(budget - budgetItem)
} else {
    // If a number was not found, what should it do here?
}
```

Comment: thank you, i believe part of the issue is i am not using 2.0. I am using the older version.

Comment: pi = pi! - pi2!
                
     budgetLabel.text = String(pi)  I am getting an error on this line. "missing argument label"