# IOS swift how can I convert string to float while using the Text property

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am doing some programming inside a TableView which is getting some Json data and one of the elements coming back is of type Float and I am having trouble using the text property on a float this is my code

```
    var latitudes = [Float]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycelia", for: indexPath) 
      // This gives error can't convert type String to Float
    cell.MyLabel.text = latitudes[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

I am new to Swift and have tried other methods such as what is explained here [Convert String to float in Apple's Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085665/convert-string-to-float-in-apples-swift#comment39877071_24088249) but can not get it to work

Comment: Actually you have it backwards. What you need to do here is convert a Float to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it into a String initializer:

```
cell.MyLabel.text = String(latitudes[indexPath.row])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support a whatever `Locale` the device may be using, you should use `NumberFormatter`. This is important because some locales use a `.` for a decimal point, whereas others (e.g. Germany) use `,`.

So, you might define a number formatter property:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let _formatter = NumberFormatter()
    _formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6  // use however many decimal places you want
    _formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 6
    return _formatter
}()
```

Then you can do:

```
cell.MyLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: latitudes[indexPath.row]))
```

This way, when considering a latitude like 42.67, a US user will see a string of `42.670000` but the German user will see the appropriate `42,670000` string.