# How to give #3f51b5 color code programmatically for shadow color in ios

Tags: ios, web-safe-colors

I want to make shadow color with `#3f51b5`.

How can I do that. hope your help. this type cannot use to do that.

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string

Answer (score 0):

after setting the color give shadow radius,offset and opacity, convert the color to rgba and use this

```
  cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2471 green:0.3176 blue:0.7098 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
  cell.layer.shadowRadius=10;
  cell.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(1, 1);
  cell.layer.shadowOpacity=1;
```

if you want to use hex color only use this
[How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string)

Comment: I want to set the color @Sumit Oberoi

Comment: this specific #3f51b5 color

Comment: you should upvote if particular helps in solving your problem @anuk

Comment: yes, I knew it , but I do not have enough reputations to voteup, I will do it whenever possible, anyway thanx @Sumit Oberoi

Answer (score 0):

you need to set shadow first

```
cell.layer.shadowRadius=8;
cell.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(-1, -1);// this make top left shadow
cell.layer.shadowOpacity=1;
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2471 green:0.3176 blue:0.7098 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```