# Why fallthrough concept of switch case not allowed in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

```
var index = 30

switch index {

   case 10  :    
      println( "Value of index is 10")
   case 20  :

   case 30  :    
      println( "Value of index is either 20 or 30")
   case 40  :    
      println( "Value of index is 40")
   default :    
      println( "default case")
}
```

Comment: Good example of fallthrough usage here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31782490/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fallthrough is allowed in Swift, but [you do have to state it explicitly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID438):

```
switch index {
case 10:
    println( "Value of index is 10")
case 20:
    fallthrough
case 30:
    println( "Value of index is either 20 or 30")
...
```

For your situation though, it's probably better to just group your cases:

```
switch index {
case 10:
    println( "Value of index is 10")
case 20, 30:
    println( "Value of index is either 20 or 30")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can write it this way (Swift 2.2 syntax):

```
switch index {
case 10:
    print("Value is: \(index)")
case 20, 30:
    print("Value is: \(index)")
default:
    print("Default value is: \(index)")
}
```