# Swift 4 : >> operator is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift4

Swift 4 : >> operator is unavailable 
Looking for replacement operator for converting HexColor to UIColor in Swift 4.0 :

Here is sample code for earlier code version in Swift 3.0.

```
public extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let index   = hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hex     = hex.substring(from: index)
            let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
            var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
            if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexValue) {
                switch (hex.characters.count) {
                case 3:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF00) >> 8)       / 15.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F0) >> 4)       / 15.0
                    blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x00F)              / 15.0
                case 4:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF000) >> 12)     / 15.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F00) >> 8)      / 15.0
                    blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00F0) >> 4)      / 15.0
                    alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000F)             / 15.0
                case 6:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)   / 255.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)    / 255.0
                    blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF)           / 255.0
                case 8:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                    blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                    alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
                default:
                    print("Invalid RGB string, number of characters after '#' should be either 3, 4, 6 or 8", terminator: "")
                }
            } else {
//                print("Scan hex error")
            }
        } else {
//            print("Invalid RGB string, missing '#' as prefix", terminator: "")
        }
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html the `>>` operator is still available, please show a MCVE.

Comment: Your code is working for me without any error in Swift 4. Is it throwing any error?

Comment: @ViniApp - I'm surprised you didn't get any warnings in Swift 4. The `hex.substring(from: index)` syntax is now deprecated.

Comment: I said that its not throwing any error. But warning is there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782490/2303865

Answer (score 0):

This code has no problems with `>>` operator in Swift 4. The only issue is the string handling. I might replace

```
let index   = hex.characters.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let hex     = hex.substring(from: index)
```

with

```
let index   = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let hex     = String(hex[index...])
```

---

Personally, I'd make a few other changes to that routine:

1. I'd make it failable initializer (e.g. `init?(...)` returning an optional). Right now the calling code has no way of knowing if the conversion to `UIColor` failed.
2. I'd simplify the above string handling, reducing it to:

   ```
   let hex = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "^#", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
   ```

   Not only does that reduce it to a single line which removes any leading `#` present, but it also means that this code will now also work if you pass it a hex string that doesn't have the leading `#`.
3. I'd use `UInt64(_:radix:)` instead of the scanner. It's just a little simpler.

Thus:

```
public extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(hex: String) {
        var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

        let hex = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "^#", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        guard let hexValue = UInt64(hex, radix: 16) else {
            print("invalid hex string")
            return nil
        }

        switch (hex.count) {
        case 3:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF00) >> 8)       / 15.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F0) >> 4)       / 15.0
            blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x00F)              / 15.0
        case 4:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF000) >> 12)     / 15.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F00) >> 8)      / 15.0
            blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00F0) >> 4)      / 15.0
            alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000F)             / 15.0
        case 6:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)   / 255.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)    / 255.0
            blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF)           / 255.0
        case 8:
            red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
            green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
            alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
        default:
            print("Invalid RGB string, number of characters after '#' should be either 3, 4, 6 or 8", terminator: "")
            return nil
        }

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```