# Cycle list of colors and set them as cell background color | UITableView | Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Say I have a list of hex colors: `{#5375ab, #D673DD, #fca565, #4f70a6, #f86cb5, #b9f3cd, #eff8a5, #f4adf9, #fe502e, #5375ab}`.

In my UITableView, is there a way to cycle through the list of colors and set each cell as one of the colors?

For example the background colors would be as such:

```
Cell 1 - backgroundColor: #5375ab
Cell 2 - backgroundColor: #D673DD
Cell 3 - backgroundColor: #fca565
```

...and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `%` modulo operator on the `indexPath.row`. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation do something like:

```
NSArray *colors = @[yourColor1, yourColor2, yourColor3];
int colorIndex = indexPath.row % colors.count;

cell.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
```

Comment: Do you know how to format the colors to allow them to be recognized as hex colors? I'm getting an error with the following code: `NSArray *colors = @[@"#5375ab", @"#D673DD", @"#fca565", @"#4f70a6", @"#f86cb5", @"#b9f3cd", @"#eff8a5", @"#f4adf9", @"#fe502e", @"#5375ab", @"#ffffff"];`

Comment: @jape either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string or simply look up what the colors actually are in rgb and create them beforehand, if they are no dynamic

Comment: Setting them as `[UIColor colorWithRed ...]` should work, right? Also, do I need as many colors as rows? It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @jape yes `colorWithRed` should work if you supply values in the range of 0.0 to 1.0. And no - you do not need to have as many colors as rows, that is what the `%` is there for.