# Customizing button background color using RGB values in iOS using objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

From past few days i am trying to change the background color of UIButton using rgb values but i am not sure why it isn't changing the color. My initial requirement was to change the color of a button by giving the hexadecimal color value. As i couldn't find a way to do that, i am trying it in the following way

```
UIColor *ButtonColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:10 green:107 blue:171 alpha:1]; 
self.LoginButton.backgroundColor = ButtonColor;
```

Am i doing wrong anywhere in the above code ..?. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: What is "some reasons" ?

Comment: Why you are allocating the UIColor?

Comment: @Matz Hi thank you for ur response. Sorry i meant that i am not sure why it isn't changing the color..

Comment: ah okay. @JAGAT has the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
self.LoginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:107.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

May be this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry but it isn't working. I am still getting a white background button instead of the above mentioned color with rob values

Comment: But i think you are allocating UIColor and there is not any require to allocate the UIColor.

Comment: Just change your code. You can allocate the UIButton not UIColor.

Comment: I am not allocating UIColor. I have commented that part

Comment: Can you please attach the screen for that

Comment: i am sorry i didn't get you would you like me to attach the story board or the code...?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your button type is **Custom**.

```
_LoginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

And try :

```
 _LoginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10/255.0 green:107/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

**EDIT** :  If you are declaring button in class file.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85/255.0 green:85/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry but it isn't working. I am still getting a white background button instead of the above mentioned color with rob values

Comment: Have you taken button in storyboard or defined in the class file?

Comment: Yup i have taken the button in storyboard. I have created the property and changed the button type to custom in attribute inspector and use the above code in viewdidload. still it isn't working...

Comment: Check your outlet again, may be it has erased.

Answer (score 0):

UIColor accepts only values between 0.0 and 1.0. So you need to divide your value by 255.

```
self.LoginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10/255.0 green:107/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Since `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` is a class method there is no need to alloc UIColor first.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

To give the color value in hexadecimal see this question:
[How can I create a UIColor from a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string)