# 'advanceBy' has been explicitly marked unavailable - Swift / Spring iOS Library

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to implement Spring iOS Animation Library, but quite a few errors were generated. 
Code in question:

```
let startIndex = hex.endIndex.advancedBy(1)
```

Additional Code:

```
if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
        let startIndex = hex.endIndex.advancedBy(1)
        _   = hex.substring(from: startIndex)
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `.advanced(by: 1)`

Comment: Why are you trying to advance past the `endIndex`? In any case, the full error message tells you the solution – "*'advancedBy' is unavailable: To advance an index by n steps call 'index(_:offsetBy:)' on the CharacterView instance that produced the index.*"

Comment: Thanks folks, the link by Leo helped me out.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to remove the `#` from the string – you could also do `String(hex.characters.dropFirst())`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33459083/2303865